# How to make an array of words? Python

Tags: arrays, words

Good afternoon, I wanted to know how to make an array of letters, for example I have a list that is the alphabet:

```
alphabet=[chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
```

And I want to do with this list a matrix of 5 * 5, which I have done, it has been this, but python gives me error

```
dimension=5
A= np.zeros((dimension,dimension))
n=0
for j in range(dimension):
    for i in range(dimension):
        A[i][j] = alphabet[n]
        n=n+1
```

The error that gives me is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Cuestionario 4.py", line 217, in <module>
    A[i][j] = alphabet[n]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

Thank you for your attention

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not come out"? What output do you have? What does `A` store afterwards?

Comment: your initializing your array to floats not strings. So its not an array of floats. So when you assign a string to the object in the array its expecting it to be a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this

```
A= np.zeros((dimension,dimension))
```

with

```
A= np.chararray((dimension, dimension))
```

Full code should look like this

```
dimension=5
A= np.chararray((dimension,dimension))
n=0
for j in range(dimension):
    for i in range(dimension):
        A[i][j] = alphabet[n]
        n=n+1
```